# pyspark crontab triggering duplicates (same) job

Tags: pyspark, cron

I have a pyspark job that I would like to run once a week.   It takes ~ 3 hrs for the job to finish

I added this entry to crontab:

```
# use /bin/sh to run commands
#
# This crontab entry runs a pyspark job once a week:
CRON_TZ=UTC
* 12 * * 3 nohup sh -x /home/me/run_my_pyspark.sh &
```

The issue I am running into is that multiple instances of the same job starts running.   Is there a to prevent multiple instances from starting up?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to find the root cause of duplicate firing from cron.

However, to prevent a Spark job firing multiple times, I have used the **file lock** approach, I hope it might help you.

```
 1. Refer a common directory and a lock file from the Spark driver
 2. If the lock file is not present
       2.1. create the lock file
       2.2. continue job execution
 3. If the lock file is present 
       3.1. get the lock file creation time
       3.2. if the creation time is recent
                    3.2.1. then abort the execution
                    3.2.2. log and alert about the error
       3.3. if the log file is older than certain interval
                    3.3.1. overwrite the file with the new version
                    3.3.2. continue job execution
```